# Cakephp, 1 foreign key on 2 or more fields in table

Tags: php, cakephp

Hy,

I have 2 tables:

-1. users- (id, name, surname, mail.....)

-2. orders- (id, date, ***owner***, ***aprowed_by***.....)

And problem is: fields owner and aprowed_by need to be foreign keys from table users and named users_id but i cant name both fields users_id. 
I linked relations in php my admin, and baked CRUD code, but ofcourse it want work.
I tried next from google and from cake site:

- Multiple relations to the same model- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html
- HABTM- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

But it want work. maybe i work something wrong, but if someone could see what kind of relations would be that or give me some tip?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Multiple relations to the same model](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model) knowledge, your models should have code like this:

**User**

```
public $hasMany = array(
      'Owned_Order' => array(
          'className' => 'Order',
          'foreignKey' => 'owner'),
      'Aprowed_Order' => array(
          'className' => 'Order',
          'foreignKey' => 'aprowed_by')
);
```

**Order**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
      'Owner' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'owner'),
      'Aprowed' => array(
          'className' => 'User',
          'foreignKey' => 'aprowed_by')
);
```

Comment: i added these code, but i needed to make a find('list') in controller and set compact for view add.ctp, and also i needed loadModel. i thought that dropdown list will be automaticli generated with these hasMany and belongsTo code. tnx.

Comment: @user3281263 - Create a new question if you don't know how to implement a find('list') for a dropdown list.